# Manipulate Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash, key

Using Ruby I need to convert this...

```
{"30"=>["Morgan", ["lib1", "lib2"]], 
 "31"=>["Morgan", ["lib9", "lib2", "lib3"]], 
 "32"=>["Gary", ["lib1", "lib2"]], 
 "33"=>["Morgan", ["lib1"]], 
 "34"=>["Morgan", []], 
 "35"=>["Morgan", []], 
 "36"=>["Morgan", ["lib3", "lib2"]], 
 "37"=>["jim", ["lib1"]]}
```

into this...

```
{"Morgan"=>[30,31,33,34,35,36], 
 "Gary"=>[32], []=>[34,35], 
 "jim"=>[37]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Define the rules of transformation.

Comment: I agree with @SergioTulentsev here, it's not really clear how you get from the input hash to the output hash—mostly why does `[]` become a part of the result, but `["lib1"]`, etc., not?

Comment: The rule of tranformation is weird but it can be achieved, check my answer.

Comment: @megas Yes but just because a single example of a problem works doesn't mean there's not some non-obvious rule that we're missing in this one. And it's odd enough that clarification is useful.

Comment: Single liner: my_hash.reduce({}){|h,(k,(v,*o))| (h[v] ||= []) << k;h}

Answer (score 2):

```
input.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=[]}) do |(k,v),res|
  (v.last.empty? ? res[[]] : res[v.first]) << k.to_i
end

=> {"Morgan"=>[30, 31, 33, 36], "Gary"=>[32], []=>[34, 35], "jim"=>[37]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newhash={}    
hash.inver­t.each {|k,v­| newha­sh[k.first­].concat [v] }
```

The `invert` method is useful for what you want to do. But i can't see how the 'lib' part of the values have something to do with the conversion. Please clarify.

Comment: This won't work if two keys have the same value, as `invert` won't merge them, but instead overwrites.

Comment: Oh, thought it could be that easy. Bad news.

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(input)          
    output = {}                     
    noLibKey = []                   
    input.each do |key, value|      
            number = key.to_i               
            name = value[0]                 
            libs = value[1]                 
            if libs.empty?                  
                    output[noLibKey] ||= []         
                    output[noLibKey] << number      
            end                             
            output[name] ||= []             
            output[name] << number          
    end                             
    return output                   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = {"30"=>["Morgan", ["lib1", "lib2"]], 
 "31"=>["Morgan", ["lib9", "lib2", "lib3"]], 
 "32"=>["Gary", ["lib1", "lib2"]], 
 "33"=>["Morgan", ["lib1"]], 
 "34"=>["Morgan", []], 
 "35"=>["Morgan", []], 
 "36"=>["Morgan", ["lib3", "lib2"]], 
 "37"=>["jim", ["lib1"]]}

B = Hash.new;
A.each do |k,i|
    if !B[i[0]].kind_of?(Array)
        B[i[0]] = Array.new;
    end
    B[i[0]]<<k
    puts "#{k} #{i[0]}"

end

B.each do |k,i|
    puts "#{k} #{i}"
end
```

as an example code :)

Comment: Ahhhh, but `B[i[0]] ||= []` is so much nicer than `if!...kind_of? ... = Array.new`!

Comment: I am not master just giving some opinion ...